# Вывод неправильного значения функции

Tags: c, функции

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_NUMBER_OF_STRINGS 1024
#define MAX_NUMBER_OF_SYMBOLS_IN_A_STRING 1024

int TextInput(char **text, int *pcountofstr){
    int i, countofstr=0;
    pcountofstr=&countofstr;
    for (i=0; i<MAX_NUMBER_OF_STRINGS; i++){
        gets(text[i]);
        if ((strcmp(text[i],"")==0)) break;
        countofstr++;
    }
    return (countofstr);
}

int main(void){
    char **text;
    int i, countofstr;
    int *pcountofstr=&countofstr;
    text = (char**) malloc(MAX_NUMBER_OF_STRINGS*sizeof(char*));
    for (i=0; i<MAX_NUMBER_OF_STRINGS; i++){
        text [i] = (char*)malloc(MAX_NUMBER_OF_SYMBOLS_IN_A_STRING*sizeof(char));
    }
    printf("Enter text(press ENT to move to a next line; press ENT for 2 times, once you've finished:\n");
    TextInput(text,pcountofstr);
    printf("Text contains of %d strings.\n\n", countofstr);
    return 0;
}
```

Функция `textinput` отвечает за ввод текста и подсчет количества строк в переменную `countofstr`. Но при вызове этой ф-ции внутри ф-ции `main()` выводит неправильные значения.

Пример:

> Enter text(press ENT to move to a next line; press ENT for 2 times,
>   once you've finished: abcd abcd
>
> Text contains of 4200832 strings.

Comment: Зачем Вам нужен указатель `pcountofstr`? Почему бы просто не написать `int countofstr = TextInput(text);`

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В `TextInput` вы ничего не записываете *по адресу, на который указывает `pcountofstr`*, более того, меняете это значение адреса. Так что у вас в `countofstr` в `main` просто неинициализированный мусор.

Уберите в `TextInput`

```
pcountofstr=&countofstr;
```

и добавьте перед `return`

```
*pcountofstr=countofstr;
```

или замените `return` на

```
return (*pcountofstr=countofstr);
```

Но, поскольку вы и так возвращаете это значение из функции, зачем возвращать его дважды? Вовсе уберите из функции `pcountofstr`, и в `main` просто присваивайте переменной возвращаемое значение:

```
countofstr = TextInput(text);
```